Tauri v2 Embedding Additional Files UnknownPath app.path().resource_dir()
I'm using tauri=2.0.0
I'm trying to access embedded json files.
When in Dev, everything is working well.
The problem comes when sharing the App on other MacBookPro (M1,M2), Sequoia.
The folder structure looks as follow:
MyApp/
     README.md/     
     build/     
     src/           
     src-tauri/
              assets/
                   user.json
                    ....
              tauri.conf.json

tauri.conf.json
...
"resources": [
        "assets/**/*"
 ]
...

capabilities/default.json
...
"permissions": [
    "core:default",
    "shell:allow-open",
    "log:default",
    "fs:default",
    {
      "identifier": "fs:allow-read",
      "allow": [
        {
          "path": "$DOCUMENT/**"
        },
        {
          "path": "$DOWNLOADS/**"
        },
        {
          "path": "$RESOURCE/**"
        }
      ]
    },
...

I ran multiple tests to see if the path().ressource_dir() would be accessible in different end points but every time it prints Err(UnknownPath)
No idea what's going on at this point
lib.rs
input
.setup(|app|{
            let resource_dir = app.path().resource_dir();
            println!("Resource directory: {:?}", resource_dir);
            let doc_alt=let resource_path = app.path().resolve("assets/user.json",BaseDirectory::Resource)
            println!("Doc Alt: {:?}", doc_alt);
            Ok(())
        })

output
Resource directory: Err(UnknownPath)
Doc Alt: Err(UnknownPath)
          


Fixed
 "resources": {
      "assets/**/*": "assets/"
    },

